# Is there a way to sort an array by a subarray's index in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, sorting

Suppose I have an array of arrays of ints, where each subarray is 2 elements.

ie:

```
[[1,2] , [3,7] , [2,9] , [10,19]]
```

Is there a way to sort this array by each subarray's first index? For the above the array, the correct solution would be:

```
[[1,2] , [2,9] , [3,7] , [10,19]]
```

Since 1 < 2 < 3 < 10

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show what you have tried so far. Explain what issues you have. You must have some code.

Comment: little hint though, look at the `.sorted(by: )` function that takes a closure in which yu can achieve this kind of ordering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this return what you want?

`[[1,2] , [3,7] , [2,9] , [10,19]].sorted(by: {$0[0]<$1[0]})`

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I'm just unfamiliar with swift syntax so I don't really understand what {$0[0]<$1[0]} does. Would you mind explaining it?

Comment: @Wallace Please read the [Swift book](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html). I'd recommend to everyone to *read the entire thing*, but in this particular case, you should read the section on closures.

Comment: @Wallace The `by:` param is a function or closure that takes two `Element`s and returns a `Bool`. If the return is `true` the first `Element` is sorted first. In an anonymous closure, `$0` and `$1` are implicitly representing the first and second parameters, respectively. `{$0[0]<$1[0]}` is a closure that returns true if the first element of the left hand side array in the array is smaller than the first element of the right hand side.